# NSUnknownKeyException error, where do I start

Tags: ios, swift

recently starting learning swift and I'm getting an error message that I'm not sure where to being with. I'm attempting to make a simple app that stores the user phone number in UserDefaults. I'm not sure if the location of where I've placed the code or another silly mistake. Thanks in advance for any help.

View Controller:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var userNumberText: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var blankView: UITextView!

    @IBAction func saveButton(_ sender: Any) {
    if(userNumberText.text?.count)! > 0 {
    let number = UserDefaults.standard.set(userNumberText.text, forKey: "number")
        }
    }



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
            let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        if let number = defaults.string(forKey: "number"){
            blankView.text = number;
        }   
}
}
```

Error Stack:

```
2018-01-27 06:36:23.863147-0500 Number Saver[1065:85326] [MC] Lazy loading NSBundle MobileCoreServices.framework
2018-01-27 06:36:23.864677-0500 Number Saver[1065:85326] [MC] Loaded MobileCoreServices.framework
2018-01-27 06:36:23.921929-0500 Number Saver[1065:85326] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<Number_Saver.ViewController 0x7fa0f9f06280> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key blankText.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f9fa12b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010f08ef41 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f9fa079 -[NSException raise] + 9
    3   Foundation                          0x000000010eaada63 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 292
    4   UIKit                               0x0000000110018117 -[UIViewController setValue:forKey:] + 87
    5   UIKit                               0x0000000110309c2d -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 109
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f99d3cd -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 317
    7   UIKit                               0x00000001103085e3 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1856
    8   UIKit                               0x000000011001f3ff -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 383
    9   UIKit                               0x000000011001fd2b -[UIViewController loadView] + 177
    10  UIKit                               0x000000011002005c -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 195
    11  UIKit                               0x00000001100208b9 -[UIViewController view] + 27
    12  UIKit                               0x000000010feeb7cf -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 122
    13  UIKit                               0x000000010feebed7 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 294
    14  UIKit                               0x000000010fefee54 -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 42
    15  UIKit                               0x000000010fe718b8 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 4737
    16  UIKit                               0x000000010fe76aeb -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1720
    17  UIKit                               0x00000001102406f8 __111-[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability _scheduleFirstCommitForScene:transition:firstActivation:completion:]_block_invoke + 924
    18  UIKit                               0x00000001106164c8 +[_UICanvas _enqueuePostSettingUpdateTransactionBlock:] + 153
    19  UIKit                               0x00000001102402f1 -[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability _scheduleFirstCommitForScene:transition:firstActivation:completion:] + 249
    20  UIKit                               0x0000000110240b6b -[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability activateEventsOnly:withContext:completion:] + 696
    21  UIKit                               0x0000000110bbea69 __82-[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 262
    22  UIKit                               0x0000000110bbe922 -[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 444
    23  UIKit                               0x000000011089b9c8 __125-[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:]_block_invoke + 221
    24  UIKit                               0x0000000110a9ab06 _performActionsWithDelayForTransitionContext + 100
    25  UIKit                               0x000000011089b88b -[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:] + 231
    26  UIKit                               0x0000000110615b25 -[_UICanvas scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 392
    27  UIKit                               0x000000010fe7536a -[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 523
    28  UIKit                               0x0000000110450605 -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:] + 369
    29  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000114bcacc0 -[FBSSceneImpl _didCreateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 338
    30  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000114bd37b5 __56-[FBSWorkspace client:handleCreateScene:withCompletion:]_block_invoke_2 + 235
    31  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000113e2933d _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    32  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000113e2e9f3 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 592
    33  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000114bff498 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 24
    34  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000114bff14e -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 464
    35  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000114bff6bd -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 45
    36  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f99d101 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    37  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fa3cf71 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 81
    38  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f981a19 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 185
    39  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f980fff __CFRunLoopRun + 1279
    40  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010f980889 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 409
    41  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001154939c6 GSEventRunModal + 62
    42  UIKit                               0x000000010fe785d6 UIApplicationMain + 159
    43  Number Saver                        0x000000010e779b57 main + 55
    44  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000113ea5d81 start + 1
    45  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: Check your Outlets in Sotryboard. You have an Outlet setup that does not exist anymore, named `blankText`.

Comment: That worked, thank you